# Excel vba - Loop in 2 columns and sort

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops, sorting

I need a macro for this case

[image]

I try to sort this list as given in the example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where got you stuck? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: I tryed with For each and While loop. I really do not known how to fix this